# Adjust pandas read_sql_query NULL value treatment?

Tags: python, pandas

When I do

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute("create table test (a float)")
for _ in range(5):
    conn.execute("insert into test values (NULL)")

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from test", engine)
#df = pd.read_sql_table("test", engine)
df.a
```

the result is a column of `None` values as opposed to `float("nan")`. This is pretty annoying if especially if you read float columns with NULL values chunk-wise.

The `read_sql_table` version works fine, since I suppose it can use type information.

Is there an easy way I can adjust `read_sql_query` to also interpret `NULL` values as `float("nan")`?

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way. Pandas does not convert all Nones (eg `pd.Series([None, None])` gives you None values and not NaN) but keeps them as object, and `read_sql_query` can never know it were supposed to be floats. If *you* know it advance which columns have to be float, you can do a `df['a'].astype(float)` on that column.

Comment: But I agree this is a problem is such case. A possible keyword argument to specify the type for a certain column (like `dtype` in `read_csv`) could maybe be useful here. You can always open an issue at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: Or a `converters` parameter, also like `read_csv`, if at all possible

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems [an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/893) was raised and something like it - the `coerce_float` argument  - was added to pandas in version 0.7.2, as per wesm's comment in the linked page:

> hi arthur, I added an option coerce_float (in the above commit) that converts Decimal -> float and fills None with NaN. Converting Decimal to float is still really slow. Will be part of 0.7.2 to be released soon

Although the description in the [pandas.read_sql_query 0.18.1 docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html) seems confusing:

> coerce_float : boolean, default True
>
> Attempt to convert values to non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating point, useful for SQL result sets

Comment: For the above example it doesn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: That's disappointing. It solved a related problem I faced, so I think it warrants being an answer here. In your case, I think you should raise a related issue on github and update/answer the question with the results.

Comment: Didn't make a difference in my case too

Comment: This might be the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330130/1509695